# amplify.js - amplify.store not storing data

Tags: javascript, mvvm, amplifyjs

I am using amplify.js with Knockout.js and I want to store data locally. I tried using this code: [amplify guide](http://craigcav.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/simple-client-storage-for-view-models-with-amplifyjs-and-knockout/)
but it isn't working for me.

**My view model**

```
define(['services/datacontext'], function (dataContext) {

    var store = amplify.store("offlineData"); // Why is agency undefined after retrieving from the store?!?!?!

    var agency = ko.observableArray([]);
    var initialized = false;

    var save = function (agency) {
        return dataContext.saveChanges(agency);
    };

    var vm = { // This is my view model, my functions are bound to it. 
        //These are wired up to my agency view
        activate: activate,
        agency: agency,
        title: 'agency',
        refresh: refresh, // call refresh function which calls get Agencies
        save: save
    };
    return vm;

    function activate() {
        if (initialized) {
            return;
        }

        initialized = true;

        if (initialized == true) {
            amplify.store("offlineData", vm.agency);
        }

        return refresh();

    }

    function refresh() {
        return dataContext.getAgency(agency);
    }
});
```

After refresh retrieves the data, I save this data to the local store. So when I make another request for this page. I would expect var store to contain this data but it is undefined.

Does anyone know how to use amplify?

Answer (score 1):

```
amplify.store("offlineData", vm.agency);
```

vm.agency is a function, therefore you need to invoke it to get its value

```
amplify.store("offlineData", vm.agency());
```

Comment: Yup, you're probably right. I prefer to use the Knockout utility `ko.util.unwrapObservable(vm.agency)`, or the 'newer' `ko.unwrap(vm.agency)`, reads nicer IMO - makes it more explicit - and also if you ever change things to be non-observable (tho unlikely) then it won't break the code.